# Trigger.io native modules, and Cordova/Phonegap plugins compatibility

Tags: cordova, trigger.io, phono

I am developping applications with Trigger.io toolkit and i am very satisfied.

However, there is a Cordova/Phonegap plugin i would like to use in my apps. This plugin is the "Phono" client that enable voice call in ios/android phonegap applications.

http://phono.com/docs

My question is about the "portability" of this module to the trigger.io "Native module" concept.

Should I immediatly give up, or is there minor ajustement to make to be able to use them in trigger.io

My question target peoples who have already work with trigger.io and/or phonegap modules/plugins.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the questions fully but the link you sent is for a JS lib. You don't need a plugin or modual for that. When you say voice call what are you trying to do, like are you trying to create a VOIP type app?

Comment: Yes, it's to add voip service to an app.
Flash or WEBRTC on modern browsers.

But in phonegap, or trigger.io, WebViews are poor implementation of web browser, so no websocket, no webrtc, no flash. A company like Phono made a  plugin for Cordova/Phonegap (see at the bottom of page : http://phono.com/docs#mobile ), to bring all what is necessary and lack in webview browser.

There is the OpenTok Phonegap plugin that i would like to be able to port to TRIGGER.IO   https://github.com/opentok/PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Ok I see what you are looking for, unfortunately there is no easy port process as there is cordova specific plugin code in each. I would venture that you could port it yourself and update it to work with trigger.io as a module but it would take some work and may still not work as expected.